# Unable to load AWS SDK in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-chrome-app

I'm poking around with [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) on writing to an S3 bucket from Javascript in a chrome app, but seem to be getting blocked by permissions.

I must include a local copy of the aws sdk:
`<script src="assets/third-party/js/aws-sdk-2.0.22.min.js"></script>`

Otherwise I get a:
`<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.22.min.js"></script>`
`Refused to load the script <script path> because it violates the following Content Security Policy`

The AWS SDK library then fails with:
`window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead.`

Am I out of luck?  @Amazon, can you make a version of your SDK for chrome apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested embedding the SDK into the [hello-world](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/hello-world) sample app provided by Google and I was able to successfully load it and list objects in an Amazon S3 bucket I own with CORS enabled.

I did get the `window.localStorage` warning, but note that it is a *warning* and should only affect you if you are using `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` (and can be worked around, see the end of this post for more).

> I must include a local copy of the aws sdk: `<script src="assets/third-party/js/aws-sdk-2.0.22.min.js"></script>`

That's right, you must embed external content when writing a Chrome app. This is due to Chrome's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy), which has strict rules about where executable code comes from. I would recommend reading through the "[Handling External Content](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external)" section of the Chrome App developer guide to learn more about how to handle these kinds of resources, as well as how to sandbox content that cannot be embedded.

#### Addendum: `window.localStorage`

**edit**: This workaround will no longer be necessary after v2.0.23 due to [this change](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/1e10952ea18f459dab37339a0786ff57ec34e69a).

If you happen to require `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials`, you can work around the `window.localStorage` issue by adding a script tag prior to the SDK like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="localStorage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aws-sdk-2.0.23.min.js"></script>
```

The `localStorage.js` file would simply redefine `localStorage` and have the following single line:

```
window.localStorage = {};
```

Note that `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials` relies on `window.localStorage` to cache your Cognito identity ID when possible. The need to cache this ID should be less important with single page applications, and therefore is okay to disable using the above technique. If you do need to cache, you can see the [AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html) API docs for getting the identity ID and storing it for later. You may also want to look at writing a [sandboxed app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#sandboxing), which would allow you to make use of `window.localStorage` as well as referencing external content and a more relaxed CSP, if needed.

Comment: setting localStorage to an empty object doesn't do anything - `window.localStorage` always remains `null` for me.